# mysql check data in sha512 encryption

Tags: php, mysql, sha512

I need to check data in sha512 encryption by MYSQL query and PHP

I can do it by md5 like this :

```
SELECT * FROM text WHERE md5(id) = '$id'
```

But , how about in sha512?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mysql 5.5+

```
SELECT * FROM text WHERE SHA2(id, 512) =  '$id'
```

### More details :

[`SHA2(str, hash_length)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2)

> Calculates the SHA-2 family of hash functions (SHA-224, SHA-256,
>   SHA-384, and SHA-512). The first argument is the cleartext string to
>   be hashed. The second argument indicates the desired bit length of the
>   result, which must have a value of 224, 256, 384, 512, or 0 (which is
>   equivalent to 256). If either argument is NULL or the hash length is
>   not one of the permitted values, the return value is NULL. Otherwise,
>   the function result is a hash value containing the desired number of
>   bits. See the notes at the beginning of this section about storing
>   hash values efficiently.
>
> The return value is a nonbinary string in the connection character
>   set.

```
mysql> SELECT SHA2('abc', 224);
        -> '23097d223405d8228642a477bda255b32aadbce4bda0b3f7e36c9da7'
```

> This function works only if MySQL has been configured with SSL
>   support. See Section 6.3.9, “Using SSL for Secure Connections”.
>
> SHA2() can be considered cryptographically more secure than MD5() or
>   SHA1().